# Rails: simple_form SyntaxError in haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

Hi i have problem with simple form gem
I received error when i rendered script:

```
app/views/docs/_form.html.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected ')'
app/views/docs/_form.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
app/views/docs/_form.html.haml:8: unterminated string meets end of file
app/views/docs/_form.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
app/views/docs/new.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_docs_new_html_haml___3494450644670928784_70227155181520'
```

file of view/docs
_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @doc do |f| 
= f.input :title
= f.input :content

= f.button :submit
```

new.html.haml

```
= render 'form'
```

and docs.controller

```
class DocsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @doc = Doc.new
  end
def create
  @doc = Doc.new(doc_params)
  if @doc.save
    redirect_to @doc
else
  render 'new'
end


end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def find_doc
  end

  def doc_params
    params.require(:doc).permit(:title, :content)
  end

end
```

I tried add tags <% %> to docs_form.html.haml but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your indentation is not correct. For a **loop** or **block** in haml, you have to indent the code under it. Do it this way:

```
= simple_form_for @doc do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.button :submit
```